# Custom ID column based on year and month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below create table code:

```
CTranID int identity(1,1) constraint pk_CTrainID Primary Key,
CustomerID AS 'PB' + 
               cast(datepart(yy,getdate()) as varchar(25)) + 
               cast(datepart(mm,getdate()) as varchar(25)) + 
               RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(CTranID AS VARCHAR(10)), 9),
```

What is happening is that when the record inserts it goes as per current year and month.
But as a testing I changed the system month and when I query in `T-SQL`, I see the previously inserted records as for the changed month.
Where in case it should have been for the month before changing the system month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of a computed column is that it gets computed every time it is accessed - if the underlying components of the computation change, so will the columns value, .

You will need to change your CustomerId column to a normal, persisted column and find another way to auto-populate it.

```
CREATE TABLE...
  CustomerID VARCHAR(50), -- i.e. not computed
```

Ideally, this will be done by the app inserting the row, but you could I guess also resort to a trigger, e.g.

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_Customer ON CUSTOMER AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE c
    SET c.CustomerID = 'PB' + cast(datepart(yy,getdate()) as varchar(25)) + 
        cast(datepart(mm,getdate()) as varchar(25)) + 
        RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(ins.CTranID AS VARCHAR(10)), 9)
    FROM Customer c 
    INNER JOIN Inserted ins on c.CTranID = ins.CTranID;
END;
GO
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1da86/1)

Comment: For what its worth, I don't like the trigger approach either as it won't be obvious how the column gets generated (although the persisted column is important). It seems like the creation of the `CustomerId` is important enough to be given proper thought and warrant an explicit step in the code inserting rows into this table, e.g. through a PROC.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a computed column. Every time you query that table the value of the column, for each row, will be calculated on the fly. That is why you are seeing changing values as you change the system clock.

Instead, store the date of creation in a column and base your calculated column on that column:

```
CREATE TABLE peter (
CTranID int identity(1,1) constraint pk_CTrainID Primary Key,
CreatedOn DateTime2 DEFAULT (SYSDATETIME()) NOT NULL, -- New Column
CustomerID AS 'PB' + cast(datepart(yy,CreatedOn) as varchar(25)) + cast(datepart(mm,CreatedOn) as varchar(25)) + RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(CTranID AS VARCHAR(10)), 9)
)

INSERT INTO peter
DEFAULT values      

SELECT * FROM peter
```

> ```
> CTranID   CreatedOn   CustomerID 
> 1         2015-05-26  PB20155000000001
> ```

Comment: If you are already using `DateTime2`, use [`SYSDATETIME()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630353.aspx) instead of `GETDATE()`

Comment: I actually prefer the solution of @radu-gheorghiu for several reasons: There is no need for the column to be computed at all. If someone updates the CreatedOn-column then the CustomerID value will also change. You will probably want to index this column and then you will need to persist it anyway.